# Unable to Get Contacts on FirefoxOS

Tags: mobile, firefox-os

I have a FirefoxOS device and I am trying to create an application to manage the contacts. I am unable to get the contacts both from the Device and the Simulator (both have 1.3 version)
Following is my code (taken from the help):

```
var cursor = navigator.mozContacts.getAll({});

cursor.onsuccess = function() {
    if (cursor.result) {
        console.log("Got contact with name: " + cursor.result.name.join(" "));
        cursor.continue();
    } else {
        alert("Done!");
    }
};

cursor.onerror = function() {
    alert("Error getting contacts");
    console.log( cursor );
};
```

Following is the segment from my manifest file:

```
...
"permissions": {
        "storage": {
            "description": "Required for storing data"
        },
        "contacts": {
            "description": "Needed to access the contacts",
            "access": "readonly"
        }
    },
...
```

It always falls to the `onerror` function. Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set in the manifest:

```
"type": "privileged",
```

?

Otherwise please post the the value of `cursor.error` when it fails.

Comment: When I run without any changes I get `error.message:"",error.name:"Not Allowed"` but when I add the `type` directive in manifest, nothing happens. Neither success gets executed nor error. Infact JS isn't working now.

Comment: Alright, so it was a permission issue. Can you put your app somewhere? Probably a typo somewhere.

Comment: Because you now run in a more restricted context, a [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/CSP) applies to your app. jQuery 1.11 does not comply to the CSP. Upgrade your jQuery version to 2.1.1 instead and all will be well.

Comment: I wasn't using *jQuery* but still upgraded to 2.1.1 and the output is the same. That is no output, nothing. I have pushed also.

Comment: It still is a CSP violation. In privileged apps it's not allowed to have a `<script>` element with code on your page. If you move the code into a separate file (e.g. contacts.js) and reference via `<script src="contacts.js"></script>` it works (just tried :-)).

You can see the CSP violation if you click DEBUG, open the console, then go back to Apps, click UPDATE, and then go back to your debug session. It's a bit weird way, but it gives you some insight.

Comment: Oh thanks alot. Plz mention all this in your original answer so that others may find help.